# Differences in meaning between synonyms for 'nonsense'

Tags: значения

Maybe this is will be difficult because of how applicable and general slang words like 'nonsense' can be, but how do the words which are roughly translated as 'nonsense' differ from one another?

The most notable ones in my view appear to be: чепуха, ерунда, чушь, вздор, мура, ахинея. Certainly feel free to mention any which I might have missed.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**чепуха** is plain nonsense

**ерунда** has a hint of unimportance

**чушь** has a hint of upset or disagreement

**вздор** is bookish

**мура** is slang

**ахинея** is mental

Also

**бред** is delirious

**нелепость** is out of place

**абсурд** is absurd

**бессмыслица** doesn't make sense

**белиберда** is colloquial

**галиматья** is close to crazy (?)

And a few modern slang ones, in order of obscenity:

**хрень**, **херня**, **хуйня**

Answer (score 1):

I would favor бред  or фигня in most cases though certainly not in more formal settings, where I'd go with ерунда.  These others I learned once but rarely hear.  Consider usage according to Google [trends](https://www.google.com/trends/explore#q=%D0%91%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%2C%20%D0%A4%D0%B8%D0%B3%D0%BD%D1%8F%2C%20%D0%95%D1%80%D1%83%D0%BD%D0%B4%D0%B0%2C%20%D0%A7%D0%B5%D0%BF%D1%83%D1%85%D0%B0%2C%20%D0%A7%D0%B5%D0%BF%D1%83%D1%85%D0%B0&cmpt=q&tz=Etc%2FGMT%2B4).  Note that searches for Brad Pitt are mixed in there so could be biased.